# md-table-pagination localization For angular material

Tags: angularjs, localization, angular-material

How can i localization [md-table-pagination](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjvLVJ?editors=1010). I want to change the **Page:** and **of** of the  md-table-pagination to language select language e.g chineses.I have googled it for couple of hours but does not found any working solution.

```
<md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="limitOptions" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{desserts.count}}" md-page-select="options.pageSelect" md-boundary-links="options.boundaryLinks" md-on-paginate="logPagination"></md-table-pagination>
```

Comment: are you looking for i18n library? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#pagination

JS

```
 $scope.labelOpts = {
     page: 'Page', // page caption
     rowsPerPage: "Rows", // caption
     of: "Of" // off title
 }
```

HTML

```
<md-table-pagination 
        md-limit="query.limit" 
        md-limit-options="limitOptions" 
        md-page="query.page" 
        md-label="labelOpts"  // md-label property
        md-total="{{desserts.count}}" 
        md-page-select="options.pageSelect" 
        md-boundary-links="options.boundaryLinks" 
        md-on-paginate="logPagination"></md-table-pagination>
```